# Can't loop over a sampler2D array after specifying WebGL2 context in Three.js

Tags: glsl, webgl2

I have been using a `sampler2D` array in my fragment shader (those are shadow maps, there can be up to 16 of them, so an array is more preferable than using 16 separate variables, of course). Then I added the WebGL2 context (`const context = canvas.getContext('webgl2');`) to the `THREE.WebGLRenderer` that I'm using and now I can't get the program to work: it says `array index for samplers must be constant integral expressions` when I attempt to access the sampler array elements in a loop like this:

```
uniform sampler2D samplers[MAX_SPLITS];

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SPLITS; ++i) {
    if (i >= splitCount) {
        break;
    }

    if (func(samplers[i])) { // that's where the error happens
      ...
    }
}
```

Is there really no way around this? Do I have to use sixteen separate variables?

(there is no direct `#version` directive in the shader but THREE.js seems to add a `#version 300 es` by default)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use dynamic indexing with samplers in GLSL ES 3.0. From [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf)

> ### 12.29 Samplers
>
> Should samplers be allowed as l-values? The specification already allows an equivalent behavior:
>
> Current specification:
>
> ```
> uniform sampler2D sampler[8];
> int index = f(...);
> vec4 tex = texture(sampler[index], xy); // allowed
> ```
>
> Using assignment of sampler types:
>
> ```
> uniform sampler2D s;
> s = g(...);
> vec4 tex = texture(s, xy); // not allowed
> ```
>
> RESOLUTION: Dynamic indexing of sampler arrays **is now prohibited** by the specification. Restrict indexing of sampler arrays to constant integral expressions.

and

> ### 12.30 Dynamic Indexing
>
> For GLSL ES 1.00, support of dynamic indexing of arrays, vectors and matrices was not mandated
>   because it was not directly supported by some implementations. Software solutions (via program
>   transforms) exist for a subset of cases but lead to poor performance. Should support for dynamic indexing
>   be mandated for GLSL ES 3.00?
>
> RESOLUTION: Mandate support for dynamic indexing of arrays **except for sampler arrays**, fragment
>   output arrays and uniform block arrays.
>
> Should support for dynamic indexing of vectors and matrices be mandated in GLSL ES 3.00?
>
> RESOLUTION: Yes.
>
> Indexing of arrays of samplers by constant-index-expressions is supported
>   in GLSL ES 1.00. A constant index-expression is an expression formed from
>   constant-expressions and certain loop indices, defined for
>   a subset of loop constructs. Should this functionality be included in GLSL ES 3.00?
>
> RESOLUTION: **No. Arrays of samplers may only be indexed by constant-integral-expressions.**

Can you use a 2D_ARRAY texture to solve your issue? Put each of your current 2D textures into a layer of a 2D_ARRAY texture then the z coord is just an integer layer index. Advantage, you can use many more layers with a 2D_ARRAY then you get samplers. WebGL2 implementations generally only have 32 samplers but allow hundreds or thousands of layers in a 2D_ARRAY texture.

or use GLSL 1.0

```js
const vs1 = `
void main() { gl_Position = vec4(0); }
`;
const vs3 = `#version 300 es
void main() { gl_Position = vec4(0); }
`;
const fs1 = `
precision highp float;

#define MAX_SPLITS 4

uniform sampler2D samplers[MAX_SPLITS];
uniform int splitCount;

bool func(sampler2D s) {
  return texture2D(s, vec2(0)).r > 0.5;
}

void main() {
  float v = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SPLITS; ++i) {
      if (i >= splitCount) {
          break;
      }

      if (func(samplers[i])) { // that's where the error happens
         v += 1.0;
      }
  }
  gl_FragColor = vec4(v);
}
`;

const fs3 = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;

#define MAX_SPLITS 4

uniform sampler2D samplers[MAX_SPLITS];
uniform int splitCount;

bool func(sampler2D s) {
  return texture(s, vec2(0)).r > 0.5;
}

out vec4 color;

void main() {
  float v = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SPLITS; ++i) {
      if (i >= splitCount) {
          break;
      }

      if (func(samplers[i])) { // that's where the error happens
         v += 1.0;
      }
  }
  color = vec4(v);
}
`;

function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert('need WebGL2');
  }
  
  test('glsl 1.0', vs1, fs1);
  test('glsl 3.0', vs3, fs3);
  
  function test(msg, vs, fs) {
    const p = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
    log(msg, ':', p ? 'success' : 'fail');
  }
}
main();


function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```